# Módulo nomeado 'tkinter' não encontrado - python

Tags: python, tkinter

Comecei a mexer na biblioteca `tkinter` do python recentemente, porém não consigo devido ao fato da biblioteca não estar sendo encontrada.

A mensagem de erro mostrada é a seguinte: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`.
Já tentei mudar o nome para Tkinter, instalar manualmente a biblioteca através de `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`, porém continua com o mesmo erro.

Estou usando o python 3.7 no PyCharm.

Código:

```
from tkinter import *
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        pass
root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter esta desde o Python 3.1, ttk onde são incluídos em todas as distribuições padrão do Python. Recomendo instalar a distribuição "ActivePython" do ActiveState, que inclui tudo o que você precisa.

```
python -m tkinter ou  python3 -m tkinter
```

Isso deve aparecer em uma pequena janela; a primeira linha no topo da janela deve mostrar a versão.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Activestate.com](https://Activestate.com)

OBS: no caso python2 o import deve ser feito com Tkinter( T em maiúsculo)